# Replacing Gherkin argument strings

Tags: ruby, cucumber, capybara, gherkin

Is there any way to replace the text of a Gherkin argument that has been passed to its corresponding step definition?

For example, let's say I have the following Gherkin step with matching Transform:

```
Given I select "any option" from the "Choose an option" dropdown

DROPDOWN_OPTION = Transform /^any option$/ do |str|
  str = all("li", :minimum => 1).sample.text
end
```

If the li it selected was "settings", I would want the results after executing that step to look like this:

```
Given I select "settings" from the "Choose an option" dropdown
```

I realize that this is not an ideal approach to writing Gherkin (or even testing in general, for that matter) but it is unfortunately a limitation that I am stuck with.

Can anyone advise?

Comment: Not sure I understand since that is how `cucumber` works. [Step Definitions](http://cukes.info/step-definitions.html) use regular expressions consistently as that is their true intention is to allow this type of behavior.

Comment: Perhaps it's just not working for me then?

I initially had this set as a transform.  Something akin to:

    `DROPDOWN_OPTION = Transform /^any option$/ do |str|
      str = all("li", :minimum => 1).sample
    end`

But when this step was executed, the results still displayed as:

    `Given I select "any option" from the "Choose an option" dropdown`

Rather than:
    `Given I select "the selected option" from the "Choose an option" dropdown`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is this what you are asking

/features/step_definitions/drop_down_steps.rb

```
Given /^I select (\w+) from the Choose an option dropdown$/ do |opt|
  #do what ever you need to here with opt
  instance_variable_set("@option_selected",DropDownOption.new(opt))
end
When /^I make it go$/ do
  #make it go
  @option_selected.go
end
Then /^I expect that it went$/ do 
  #test that it went with the opt selected
  @option_selected.went?
end
Then /^I expect it is still (\w+)$/ do |opt|
  @option_selected.selected == opt
end
```

/features/drop_down_option.feature

```
Feature: DropDownOption
  This is to test that I can send a DropDownOption away
  but it will still be itself

  Scenario: Selected Stuff
    Given I select stuff from the Choose an option dropdown
    When I make it go
    Then I expect that it went
    Then I expect it is still stuff
```

What this does is pass each match group into the block below allowing you to set things like instance variables and to perform actions on them. So in my first step it creates an instance variable called `@option_selected` from the "stuff" regex match. thes second step tells this instance variable to `#go` and the third step makes sure it `#went?`. Finally the forth step makes sure that even though it went away it is still the same "option".

This is obviously an extremely generic example just to show how features and step definitions work. It assumes a lot of things but basically it would work with a class like this

```
class DropDownOption
  def initialize(opt)
    @opt = opt
    @is_here = true
  end
  def go
    @is_here = false
  end
  def selected
    @opt
  end
  def is_here?
    @is_here
  end
  def went?
    !is_here?
  end
end
```

**Update**

If you want to transform something then it must act as a capture group

```
Feature: RandomString
  Scenario: With a Random String
    Given I type "random string" into the title field
    Then I want it to be a String

Transform /^I type ? "(.*)"$/ do |str|
  rand(36**15).to_s(36)
end
Given /^(I type "(?:.*)") into the title field$/ do |str|
  instance_variable_set("@random_string",str)
end
Then /^I want it to be a String$/ do
  puts @random_string
  expect(@random_string).to be_kind_of(String)
end
```

output

```
Feature: RandomString

  Scenario: With a Random String                     # features\random_string.feature:2
    Given I type "random string" into the title field # features/step_definitions/random_steps.rb:4
    Then I want it to be a String                    # features/step_definitions/random_steps.rb:7
    qxv75si91k2u10s  #this is the transformed string it is random but will not alter the feature step definition
```

When the capture group matches a transformer the transformation will take place and this will be piped in in place of the original capture.

Feature Definitions are meant to be fixed for testing purposes. They are meant to be plainly worded and be handled by matchers. They are not meant to be dynamically implemented as this would take away from their true purpose.

Comment: It's not quite what I was asking, sadly (although...I actually like what you've done here anyway and have a couple of areas I would like to apply this to; hardly a waste of time).

I just restructured my question a little to be more specific though.  What I am asking is essentially, if the Gherkin is: `Given I have "a random string"`, how can I have it print `Given I have "dj3(42^&e6he@3"` in the results?

Comment: i.e. how do I substitute a Gherkin parameter with a different string.

Comment: @DavidAdams I think I understand your concept now but what do you want it to transform into?

Comment: To another string in general, really.  When a test fails, the manual team will go through the report that was generated and attempt to retrace the specific steps that were executed.  Our Gherkin files might read `Given I type "a random string" into the title field`, but in the results, we want them to see `Given I type "dj3(42^&e6he@3" into the title field` so that they know the exact information that was inserted.  Almost all of these substitutions are from one string to another -- just giving more specific information about the actions performed.  Make sense?

Comment: @DavidAdams It makes sense I am just not sure it is possible since the match occurs prior to transformation. Transforms are to handle matches not to alter the match itself. I have added an example to show you.

Comment: Yeah, I think you are correct.  I do not believe it can really be done -- but I do appreciate the assistance all the same.  If only it wasn't a pipe dream ;)  It would have handled quite elegantly.

Comment: @DavidAdams no problem you could make a feature request but I won't hold my breath as this deviates from all standard testing procedures. Best of luck glad I could help in some way.

Answer (score 1):

Rather than rewriting your source Gherkin, it seems like your main objective really is to manipulate your *results*, not your input.  If that is your goal, simply create a [custom formatter](https://github.com/cucumber/cucumber/wiki/Custom-Formatters).  By overriding the AfterStep, you can insert the value into the results and communicate what you need.

Comment: nice i did not even know about these. I usually just use RSpec but I am going to see what these are all about.

Comment: Ugh they make it seem much easier than it actually appears to be this is awesome though thanks for posting as I would not have realized how many call backs were available

Answer (score 0):

Although, cucumber doesn't care about the order of the keywords, the convention is to write your steps according to the following:

```
Given the context
When action
Then expectation
```

So to change your scenario I would write:

```
Given I have options
When I choose "whatever" dropdown
Then I expect ...
```

Comment: Actually, that was our initial approach.  I set the team to write Gherkin just like that -- but unfortunately, this approach was not conducive to the way our organization is structured internally.  The manual testers (rather than the developers or even the automation team) are the ultimate benefactor of these automated tests, so the Gherkin had to be rewritten to be far more traceable and specific.